# Download old revision of Google Play Services Respository (Android SDK)

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, android-sdk-manager

I am trying to setup a **build server** for Android Apps on ubuntu with **Jenkins**.

I installed a fresh copy of Android SDK and its packages. I got the latest version of `Google play Services Repository` that is `v10.0.1`.

**Problem:** My project uses `v9.0.1` of `Google Play Services` & `Firebase` and I cannot update the library version in my project as other modules included in my project uses this version (Updating to newer version arises conflict).

So I want to know is there a way to download/install the older revisions of Google Play Services Repository in ubuntu using terminal?

**Edit:** I am getting these error on executing `gradle wrapper` command in project directory using terminal.

> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.0.1/firebase-core-9.0.1.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.0.1/firebase-core-9.0.1.jar
>            https://jitpack.io/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.0.1/firebase-core-9.0.1.pom
>            https://jitpack.io/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.0.1/firebase-core-9.0.1.jar
>            file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.0.1/firebase-core-9.0.1.pom
>            file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.0.1/firebase-core-9.0.1.jar
>        Required by:
>            KyorPatients:app:unspecified
>
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.0.1/firebase-messaging-9.0.1.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.0.1/firebase-messaging-9.0.1.jar
>            https://jitpack.io/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.0.1/firebase-messaging-9.0.1.pom
>            https://jitpack.io/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.0.1/firebase-messaging-9.0.1.jar
>            file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.0.1/firebase-messaging-9.0.1.pom
>            file:/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.0.1/firebase-messaging-9.0.1.jar
>        Required by:
>            KyorPatients:app:unspecified
>
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.1.
>        Required by:
>            KyorPatients:app:unspecified
>
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.1.
>            Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-crash/9.0.1/firebase-crash-9.0.1.pom'.
>             Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-crash/9.0.1/firebase-crash-9.0.1.pom'.
>              repo.jfrog.org: Name or service not known
>
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1.
>        Required by:
>            KyorPatients:app:unspecified
>
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1.
>            Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/9.0.1/play-services-location-9.0.1.pom'.
>             Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/9.0.1/play-services-location-9.0.1.pom'.
>               repo.jfrog.org

Comment: The Google Play services Repository has every prior version.

Comment: @ianhanniballake then how to go about it? It only downloads the latest version.

Comment: There's one version of the Repository. The repository contains every version of Google Play services. Show your code and the error you are receiving.

Comment: @VipulAsri is it not possible to set in build.gradle the version u need?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Please see `Edit-1`.

Comment: @rakeshkashyap I am building project using terminal.

Comment: So what's in the `:/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase` directory it is attempting to find it in? Is that actually your SDK directory?

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes it is my actual android SDK directory but it only has the latest Google Play Services version that is `10.0.1`.